# Tkinter Frame-How to fix Resulation Problem while adding Label

Tags: python, tkinter, tabs

I'm Bloodly Beginner in Python. I was learning to create tabs in python using tkinter pkg. I have successfully created 2 tabs, but I can't show Text (Label) in both tab. When I show only 1 text in one tab (`heading.pack()`) it works perfectly. But when I show another text in Tab 2 (`heading2.pack()`), The frame Resulation Broked. I have also set width and height in `Frame` Option. I want to fix resulation(Before adding 2nd text resulation). Here is Before and after Screenshots

[Before adding 2nd Text](https://i.ibb.co/0CNP45c/2021-09-24-14-10-33-NEW-GUI-E-bomb-py-Python-Projects-Visual-Studio-Code.png)
[After adding 2nd Text](https://i.ibb.co/SNPMnYv/2021-09-24-14-11-36-NEW-GUI-E-bomb-py-Python-Projects-Visual-Studio-Code.png)

Here is The Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root=Tk()
root.title('Tab Widget')
root.geometry('600x400')

book=ttk.Notebook(root)
book.pack(pady=2)

tab1=Frame(book,width=600,height=500,bg='white')
tab2=Frame(book,width=600,height=500,bg='white')

tab1.pack(fill='both',expand=1)
tab2.pack(fill='both',expand=1)

book.add(tab1,text='Tab 1')
book.add(tab2,text='Tab 2')

heading=Label(tab1,text='This is Tab 1',font='arial 20 bold',bg='white')
heading2=Label(tab2,text='This is Tab 2',font='arial 20 bold',bg='white')

heading.pack() #Show Text in Tab 1
heading2.pack() #Show Text in Tab 2

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `heading.pack()`, `tab1` will be shrink to the size of the label.  And if you don't call `heading2.pack()`, `tab2` will still have size 600x500. So the notebook client area will be kept at 600x500.

However when you call `heading2.pack()`, `tab2` will be shrink to the size of the label as well which cause the notebook client area to be shrink as well.

You can avoid the above size adjustment by changing:

```py
book.pack(pady=2)
```

to

```py
book.pack(pady=2, fill='both', expand=1)
```

so that notebook will use all the available space of the root window.

Also note that the following two lines are not necessary and can be removed:

```py
tab1.pack(fill='both',expand=1)
tab2.pack(fill='both',expand=1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro! You are a Genius. It's really worked. But I want something More. I want a content toggle like windows 7 have. I don't need the ui like win7 (It's Not possible in tkinter). I just want win7 'More details' content toggle. here is an screenshot [Click Me](https://digitalmarketing.temple.edu/jsmith/wp-content/uploads/sites/97/2017/07/IC725966.png)

Comment: You better raise another question with whatever you have tried and state the problem you came across.

Comment: I have created one on another subject. Please Help Me (If u can). [Here is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69323864/tkinter-how-to-add-a-canvas-frame-in-ttk-notebook)